# RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions

Tags: ninja, stylegan

I've downloaded an implementation of stylegan2 from the following [github](https://github.com/rosinality/stylegan2-pytorch):

I added the path to my PYTHONPATH variable and now when importing their models I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions
```

I'm working on our University computers, it seems that cpp_extension.py is only looking for an installation of ninja that is local under /usr/local/bin however I don't have the permissions to install anything there.
I was able to use pip to install Ninja on my virtual environment. Is there any possible way of having this piece of code use ninja from there?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try

```
pip install ninja
```

it works for me

https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/issues/39#issuecomment-900970462